# paketo-buildpack spring-boot bootBuildImage ca-certificates binding issue

Tags: spring-boot, certificate, paketo

I am trying to attach `ca-certificates` (`pem` files) to the docker image produced by spring-boot gradle plugin(buildpacks). The command I am using is `./gradlew bootBuildImage`. This is working fine locally and is adding the certificates but when I run this from my gitlab pipeline I am getting the below errors:

[image: bootBuildImage errors]

I added some logging to the pipeline and it seems that even though the files (pem & type) are present and have the appropriate permissions, the pipeline runner is probably not having access to those, hence it fails. I dont see how I can add the files differently or execute a command in the builder to get them via wget/curl..

Here is my `build.gradle` configuration:

[image: gradle bootBuildImage configuration]

and the `pem` files are stored like this:

[image]

The error is not very helpful and documentation is not very great. Any idea is welcome.

I have added

```
    environment = [
        "BP_LOG_LEVEL": "debug"
]
```

and the `/platform` related sections (aside from the originally shared log) are here(mentioned a few times) :

[image]

EDIT: The certificates I am trying to add are AWS RDS ones. I did try changing the buildpacks builder image in an attempt to use a more appropriate (adoptium) one (containing the AWS root certificate) https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8233223 but with no luck.

I get the impression that it is a gitlab issue and have started exploring passing the pem files to the EKS pod differently.. maybe via SERVICE_BINDING_ROOT and k8s secrets.

Comment: Could you link to your full build log? The screenshot isn't enough info. Thanks

Comment: @Daniel Mikusa There is not much more to the build log. The important bit is already provided. I get the impression that the gitlab ci setup is probably not allowing the binding files to be mounted to the builder image, even though the files are present and with the right permissions :/

Comment: Try adding an environment variable to your `build.gradle` config, `BP_LOG_LEVEL=debug`. That should trigger the buildpacks to output a lot of additional information. I thought maybe you had that enabled already, but if all you're seeing is what's in the graphic, then it's not enabled. That'll give you pages and pages of output, included will be the actual contents of `/platform`, so you'll be able to see if the binding is present.

Comment: @DanielMikusa I have editied the questions and added some extra screenshot of logging: `    [creator]     Platform Bindings: [{Name: ca-certificates Path: /platform/bindings/ca-certificates Type:  Provider:  Secret: []}]`

Comment: Yes, sounds like you are on the right track, suspecting Gitlab CI. Something is not working right with the bindings. The volume mount is happening because it creates the `ca-certificates` folder, but for some reason the volume mount is empty. The line that says "Platform Contents" would list all of the files in the binding and it's empty. I don't unfortunately know why that might be happening perhaps someone else might know.

Comment: so gitlab pipeline job (spins up a k8s pod) -> executes everything in a docker container that I specify (that does not have docker installed) -> fetches the builder - builder does the job. The question is which docker daemon is being used here ? Seems like the docker daemon does not have access to the files or so

Comment: That would be my thought as well.